# Dictionary(grouping: people, by: with 2 items in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

I have a data like this

```
 "geoData": [
  {

    "lat": 50.26877,
    "long": 19.034,
    "msg": "TEST 3",
    "geoRadius": 30.48,
    "pri" : 1
  },
  {
    "lat": 50.26877,
    "long": 19.034,
    "msg": "TEST 2",
    "geoRadius": 30.48,
    "pri" : 2
  },
  {
    "lat": 50.26877,
    "long": 10.034,
    "msg": "TEST 1",
    "geoRadius": 30.48,
    "pri" : 1
  }
  {
    "lat": 50.26877,
    "long": 10.034,
    "msg": "TEST 4",
    "geoRadius": 30.48,
    "pri" : 2
  }
]
```

Now i want to have a result dictionary as group by latitude and longitude and sort by pri

I tried something like this

```
        let result = Dictionary(grouping: geoNotifications,
                            by: { (geoNotification)->Bool in
                                return geoNotification.latitude && geoNotification.longitude })
```

But it doesn't work
Can someone share the logic for the same?

Comment: Please share some code to show what you have already tried

Comment: updated question please have a look @Niali Kiddle

Comment: So yo want a dictionary with 2 keys lat and long which will contains all lat and long respectively in an array ?

Comment: Add the final result you want to achieve for the above JSON.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

In the code you have given, I assume `geoNotifications` is an `array of struct/objects` similar to the below code:

```
struct GeoNotification
{
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var msg: String
    var geoRadius: String
    var pri: Int

    init(dict: [String:Any])
    {
        self.latitude = dict["lat"] as! Double
        self.longitude = dict["long"] as! Double
        self.geoRadius = dict["geoRadius"] as! String
        self.msg = dict["msg"] as! String
        self.pri = dict["pri"] as! Int
    }
}
```

Having an array of GeoNotification objects, we can achieve both of your requirements as:

**1. Grouping using `longitude`**

```
var dict = Dictionary(grouping: geoNotifications) { $0.longitude }
```

**Result:**

```
["10.034000000000001": [geoNotification1, geoNotification2] , "19.034": [geoNotification3, geoNotification4]]
```

**2. Sorting with `pri`**

```
for (key, value) in dict
{
    dict[key] = value.sorted(by: { $0.pri < $1.pri })
}
```

In the above code, I've picked every key-value pair from the `dict` we got earlier and sorted the value(it's an array of `GeoNotification` objects) according to `pri`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084188/show-json-as-tableview-section-and-tableview-row-in-swift-4-2-without-decodable can u pls help me with i want to do it using nsurlsession